# Is there a way to add a specific tag to a group of objects and is there a collision detection event?

Tags: java, swing, animation, collision-detection

I want to dynamically create JLabels "Bullets" while I also generate JLabels "Shields" via a mouseDrag event.  Bullets would generate on random sides of a JFrame and move forward/down/left/right depending on the side they're on.

I want to add a specific tag, like "bullet" or "shield" and check collision with if they clash, like I would in Unity. I know that java isn't really made game-wise, but I need to know if I there is an official way that I overlooked, or that I have to do it the inefficient way (iterating through each array and finding collisions).

Ideally I wouldn't have to add them to an array at all, and just check if an object collides with the specific "tag" that would be the same for each generated bullet or shield.

I want something like this:

```java
JLabel l = new JLabel();
l.setBounds(x,y,20,20); 

l.setBackground(Color.black);
l.setOpaque(true);
l.setTag("shield"); //what I would imagine it looked like 
g.getContentPane().add(l); //I have a JFrame g
g.repaint();  

//what I would imagine the collision event and collision check looked like 

Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
        //collision check
    }
}

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,1);
```

Comment: Much better to not make your bullets or your shields extend JLabel but rather to use a more lightweight construct, and have them be logical (non-GUI) classes that are represented by image sprites in a JPanel's paintComponent method. Also, don't use `java.util.Timer` and TimerTask but rather instead use the Swing Thread-safe [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) .

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Timer` - it will break Swing.  You "could" use `putClientProperty`/`getClientProperty`, but Swing components are really designed for this type of work - better make use of a custom painted route instead

Comment: *iterating through each array and finding collisions* - sound good to me.